# What is the proper FLOWCHART notation for a process that pushes and pulls as part of the same flow?

Tags: uml, flowchart

I have been tasked with documenting flows of applications that interact with a company UI. UML was the specified format to use, but it seems that anything resembling UML is fine to use.

So instead I am using a standard flowchart notation. My question is: what is the proper way to represent a process does the following steps, consecutively, as distinct operations:
a. Vendor Process sends new orders to a data-storage system, where they are saved as 'NEW' and await processing
b. Same Vendor Process polls that same storage system to see if older orders (with status 'PROCESSED') need to be sent over to the fulfillment system (via API call)

See image for the very rough draft - names and certain details redacted.
I feel the repeated use of the VENDOR process is wrong, but trying to depict the multiple actions of the process otherwise results in a very messy diagram.

[image: sample flow]

Comment: You do know that flowcharts are not part of UML? In UML you can use Activity diagrams as an alternative, but the notation is a bit different.

Comment: Currently it is difficult to answer, are (a) and (b) consecutive like they seem to be (`a process that a. `... `then b.` ...) or done in parallel ? Mainly if consecutive when the pooling (b) stops, when all messages sent during (a) are processed ? Still if consecutive all the orders must be placed in data-storage before the first order is managed in (b) ? Are all the orders removed from the  data-storage during (b), or only some of them or none ? Depending on the answers the data-storage can be useless. So please edit your question to clarify it

Comment: @bruno I made the change to the question in order to clarify. For the sake of this exercise, assume there is no parallel processing; all is sequential. No orders are removed. step a inserts, step b exports and presumably updates status to 'EXPORTED' (forgot to account for that)

Comment: @GeertBellekens I was trying to find the best fit and now agree that Activity Diagram fits best for actual UML. What is unclear to me is whether only Activities can be represented in that notation, or whether one also depicts the entities that are performing that activity. In my case, there are multiple programs sending or retrieving info. Do I leave out specifying the Entity and just represent all the actions as a flow?

Comment: `is whether only Activities can be represented in that notation, or whether one also depicts the entities that are performing that activity` : the first, an activity is a behavior, for instance an activity can define the actions performed by an operation, and the entity performing the activity is not relevant.

Comment: it seems (a) and (b) are separated because at a moment the vendor does (a) and at an other moment he does (b) but not necessary just after (a), so in fact you have two activities, one for (a) and one for (b)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like UML Sequence Diagrams are more suitable for this situation. You can show multiple distinct chains of calls more clearly. Thanks for the help
[image]